# Modifying T5 for sequence labelling

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to modify the T5-model as a sequence labelling task (to do NER).
I create my model class by taking the last hidden states of the T5-model and add a linear layer with 3 out-features (for simple IOB-tags).
Here is my model class:

```
class Seq2SeqTokenCLS(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Seq2SeqTokenCLS, self).__init__()
        
        self.num_labels = 3
        self.base_model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-small')

        # average of n last hidden layers
        self.layers = 3
        
        # change beam search or greedy search here
        # Suggested parameters from the T5 paper: num_beams = 4 and length penalty alpha = 0.6
        self.base_model.config.num_beams = 1 # <-- change to 1 for greedy decoding
        self.base_model.config.length_penalty = 0.6 # <-- comment this out for greedy decoding

        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.5)
        self.dense = nn.Linear(in_features=512 * self.layers, out_features=self.num_labels)
        
    def forward(self, input_ids, attn_mask, labels):

        hidden_states = self.base_model(
            input_ids, 
            attention_mask=attn_mask,
            output_hidden_states=True
            )

        hidden_states = torch.cat([hidden_states['decoder_hidden_states'][-(n+1)] for n in range(self.layers)], dim=2)
        
        logits = self.dense(self.dropout(hidden_states))

        loss = None
        loss_fct = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(weight=class_weights)
        # Only keep active parts of the loss
        if attn_mask is not None:
            active_loss = attn_mask.view(-1) == 1
            active_logits = logits.view(-1, self.num_labels)
            active_labels = torch.where(
                active_loss, labels.view(-1), torch.tensor(loss_fct.ignore_index).type_as(labels)
            )
            loss = loss_fct(active_logits, active_labels)
        else:
            loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
        
        return {'logits':logits,
                'loss':loss}
```

However, I am confused about how should do inference in this approach. Should I use the `.generate` function as when T5 has a standard LM head? If that is the case, then I don't know how to inherit the function into my new model class...

Or can I use a normal evaluation loop?
*E.g. something like this?:*

```
predictions = []
all_labels = []

with torch.no_grad():
    for batch in tqdm(test_loader):
        input_ids = batch['input_ids'].to(device)
        attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'].to(device)
        labels = batch['labels'].to(device)
        outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, 
                        attn_mask=attention_mask
                        )
        
        for sample, lab in zip(outputs['logits'],labels):
            preds = torch.argmax(sample, dim=1)
            predictions.append(preds)
            all_labels.append(lab)
```

I would still like to experiment with beam search...

Comment: What is the particular reason to go with an EncoderDecoder model for this particular task, compared to an Encoder-only architecture like BERT?

Comment: Mainly, because I was asked to in an exam... But the reasoning behind is to use the previous predictions of labels when predicting the next label. Kinda like they do in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-nlp-task-using-sequence2sequence-model-from-zero-to-hero-c193c1bd03d1) - although they are using LSTMs and Keras, and I want to use a transformer-based Seq2Seq-model like T5 and PyTorch.